# Verbatim with direct lua

Tags: luatex, verbatim

I would like to add newlines inside a verbatim, through `\directlua`. Why is there no newline in the first `verbatim`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,verbatim}
\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.print([[\unexpanded{\begin{verbatim}]]..'one\ntwo'..[[\end{verbatim}}]])}
\begin{verbatim}
one
two
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the use of this? You can just type in strings: no macros or special characters will be accepted.

Comment: @egreg, The use is that the string `'one\ntwo'` is actually read from a JSON file, which I wrote to with Python, which used a `\n`. Thanks to TeXnician's solution I now know I have to replace all occurences of `'\n'` in the JSON by `'\r'`, and then it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you do want to insert a carriage-return line-feed (actually carriage return is sufficient). So the following will insert one:

[image: verbatim]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,verbatim}
\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.print([[\unexpanded{\begin{verbatim}]]..'one\rtwo'..[[\end{verbatim}}]])}
\begin{verbatim}
one
two
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I have no idea why (I thought Linux didn't use the `\r`), but it works!

Comment: `\r` seems sufficient

Comment: @Carucel You're right, Linux doesn't use it. But we're not talking about Linux, but how TeX reads output Lua passes through. So in this case `\r` seems necessary.

Comment: in general you need to insert whatever is made active by `\obeylines` which is character 10 (`^^M`) which is used as that is the usual setting of `\endlinechar`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, that was behind my understanding, but seems of course very logical. Why don't you add a more detailed answer?